# OpenCart extension location folder or directory

Tags: location, directory, opencart

I want to look at the code of an existing and installed shipping extension of OpenCart 2.0.1.1. Where do I find extension files? Is it supposed to be in root folder? I don't see any files related to the extension in question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not a programming question, contact OpenCart for this information

Answer (score 2):

Check `catalog/model/shipping/` directory where all shipping files are stored.